# i try to combine rows in one column but there was an error in my syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    Elm_EmployeeId as 'Badge', 
    Left(T_EmployeeLeave , Len(T_EmployeeLeave) - 1) As 'a' 
from
    (select 
         E2.Elm_EmployeeId as 'Badge2', 
         (select Elm_EmployeeId
          from T_EmployeeLeave E1)
     from 
         T_EmployeeLeave E2)
```

Error is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Is this PHP? because if it is there are many syntax errors. It looks more like SQL, for which you may never get help for unless you change the label.

Answer (score 1):

1.you select **Elm_EmployeeId** and **T_EmployeeLeave** from a subquery but in the subquery u don't have these two columns what you have is badge2 and a non_named column

2. the   *select Elm_EmployeeId from T_EmployeeLeave E1* is meaningless
3. the query is miserable i can't even tell what excatly you want